# How to Create a dynamic date filter tables in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

My model

```
public class GoldLedger {
    @jakarta.persistence.Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE)
    private LocalDate pledgeddate;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String billnum;
    private Long billamount;
    
    private String name;
    
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE)
    private LocalDate returndate;
```

my controller

```
@Controller
public class GoldLedgerController {

    @Autowired
    private GoldLedgerService goldLedgerService;

    @GetMapping("/goldledger")
    public String getAllGoldLedgerEntry(Model model,@Param("keyword") String keyword) {

        model.addAttribute("goldledgerall", goldLedgerService.getAllGoldLed(keyword));
        model.addAttribute("keyword",keyword);
        return "goldledger";

    }

    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/goldledger/findGoldDataById/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public Optional<GoldLedger> findGoldDataById(Long id) {
        return goldLedgerService.findGoldData(id);
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/goldLedger/addToGoldLedger", method = { RequestMethod.PUT, RequestMethod.GET })
    public String addToLedger(GoldLedger goldLedger) {
        goldLedgerService.addToLedger(goldLedger);
        return "redirect:/newgoldbill";
    }

    

}
```

my service

```
@Service
public class GoldLedgerService {
@Autowired
private GoldLedgerRepository goldLedgerRepository;


public List<GoldLedger> getAllGoldLed(String keyword) {
    if(keyword != null) {
        return goldLedgerRepository.search(keyword);
    }
    else {
        return goldLedgerRepository.findAll();
    }

}

public void addToLedger(GoldLedger goldLedger) {
    
    goldLedgerRepository.save(goldLedger);
    
}

public Optional<GoldLedger> findGoldData(Long id) {
return goldLedgerRepository.findById(id);
}

}
```

my repository

```
public interface GoldLedgerRepository extends JpaRepository<GoldLedger, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT c FROM GoldLedger c WHERE CONCAT(c.billnum, ' ') LIKE %?1%")
    public List<GoldLedger> search(String Keyword);
}
```

my html

```
                                <table
                                    class="table table-bordered border-dark table-striped table-hover my-3" id="table">

                                    <thead>
                                        <tr style="text-align: center;">

                                            <th scope="col">Bill Number</th>
                                            <th scope="col">Pledged Date</th>
                                            <th scope="col">Bill Amount</th>
                                            
                                            <th scope="col">Customer Name</th>
                                            
                                            <th scope="col">Return Date</th>
                                        


                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr th:each="goldledger:${goldledgerall}"
                                            th:style="${goldledger.onepercent}!= null? 'background-color:red'">


                                            <th scope="row" th:text="${goldledger.billnum}"
                                                style="text-align: center;"></th>
                                            <td th:text="${goldledger.pledgeddate}" nowrap></td>
                                            <td th:text="${goldledger.billamount}"></td>
                                            
                                            <td th:text="${goldledger.name}"></td>
                                            
                                            <td th:text="${goldledger.itemdescription}"></td>
                                            <td th:text="${goldledger.itemweight}"></td>
                                            <td th:text="${goldledger.returndate}" nowrap></td>
                                            
                                            <td>
```

I want to filter and show my table data based on user selection like this

[image]

or by using to date pickers.but i am stuck here .i  researched through a lot but i cant find any possible solution.i am a beginner and took a real time scenario of my father's business to develop an spring app,this is my last stage in the whole app.someone help me with this.